# how do I set up client-side AJAX polling

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I've beat my head on this until it's gone soft.  Time to consult with the experts!

My app spawns a number of Delayed::Jobs.  I'd like to provide the user with visual feedback on the state of those jobs as they are running.  So assume I have a Job < ActiveRecord::Base model that has a name, a state (IDLE, QUEUED, RUNNING, SUCCEEDED, FAILED) and a status string, and that the state and status are typically updated asynchronously.

Also assume a view template with a `<div id='job-status'></div>` element as a place to display the Jobs status.  Oh, also assume I'm using Rails3 with jQuery.

For maximum portability, I'd like to use javascript-initiated client-side polling.  I know a bit of javascript (jQuery methods, setTimeout, etc), but I haven't found the blend of Rails and jQuery functions to do this in a sensible way.

Succinctly, if you had an ActiveRecord Job model with name, state, and status, what would you put in your controllers/jobs_controller.rb and what views/jobs/ would implement?  And does the server generate html or JSON or XML to update the #job-status div?  (I realize this is a broad set of questions -- I'm not expecting a full answer, just enough pointers to piece it together.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should make an ajax call by jquery to a json enabled method on you controller which send back data.

Using that data you can update the contents of div element with effect by method like `$("#somediv").html(ajax_result)`

Here is a real sample:

```
var linkHtml = $("#searchNumber").html();
$("#message").empty();
var aurl = "/Prospect/SearchNumberAuth?number=" + $("#MSISDN").val() ;
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    url: aurl,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#holdNumber").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#searchNumber").empty().html("<image src='../../Content/images/jquery-ui/load-indicator.gif'/>");
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $("#message").fadeIn(1500).html(function() {
            if (response[0] == "Exist") {
                $("#holdNumber").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#MSISDN").attr("readonly", "readonly");
                $("#searchNumber").fadeOut("slow");
                return existMsg;
            } else if (response[0] == "Sold") {
                $("#searchNumber").empty().html(linkHtml).fadeIn("slow");
                return soldMsg;
            } else if (response[0] == "Hold") {
                $("#searchNumber").empty().html(linkHtml).fadeIn("slow");
                return holdMsg;
            } else
                $("#searchNumber").empty().html(linkHtml).fadeIn("slow");
            return notExistsMsg;
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#searchNumber").empty().html(linkHtml).fadeIn("slow");
    },
    complete: function() {
    }
});
```

And here is the server side code in controller class that can be easily ported to Rails:

```
    public JsonResult SearchNumberAuth(long number)
    {
        return this._searchNumber(number);
    }
```

which in `_searchNumebr` method I will return a `JsonResult`.

You can see more details in [website](http://reg.rightel.ir) although it's in Persian but you can see the js code by FireBug in ProspectView.js and the result in second tab.

Comment: Jani: +1 for addressing one third of my question: use JSON for the server => client response.  Thanks for that.  But the other parts I'm stuck on are (a) how to construct the JSON in a Rails controller or view and (b) how to start and stop the periodic polling.